# Pygame not reading any values from PS3 controller

Tags: python, controller, pygame, external

I have been trying to set up a PS3 controller and be able to read analog input values from it, but whenever I press down or move any of the joysticks it doesn't read anything and returns false for everything.

I have been using various test codes I have found online for the controller and none of them seem to work. I'm starting to think it may be a hardware issue, but I'm still unsure.

```
import os
import pprint
import pygame


class PS3Controller(object):

    controller = None
    name = None
    axis_data = None
    button_data = None
    hat_data = None

    def init(self):
        """Initialize the joystick components"""

        pygame.init()
        pygame.joystick.init()
        self.controller = pygame.joystick.Joystick(1)
        self.controller.init()

    def listen(self):
        """Listen for events to happen"""

        if not self.axis_data:
            self.axis_data = {}

        if not self.button_data:
            self.button_data = {}
            for i in range(self.controller.get_numbuttons()):
                self.button_data[i] = False

        if not self.hat_data:
            #D - Pad
            self.hat_data = {}
            for i in range(self.controller.get_numhats()):
                self.hat_data[i] = (0, 0)

        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.JOYAXISMOTION:
                    self.axis_data[event.axis] = round(event.value, 2)
                elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
                    self.button_data[event.button] = True
                elif event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
                    self.button_data[event.button] = False
                elif event.type == pygame.JOYHATMOTION:
                    self.hat_data[event.hat] = event.value

                # Insert your code on what you would like to happen for each event here!
                # In the current setup, I have the state simply printing out to the screen.

                #os.system('clear')
                #pprint.pprint(self.button_data)
                pprint.pprint(self.axis_data)
                #pprint.pprint(self.hat_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ps3 = PS3Controller()
    ps3.init()
    ps3.listen()
```

Comment: I think your code was copied incorrectly. The indentation is wrong. Can you please update your question with the correct code? Just paste it in, select it, and press CTRL-K

Comment: hope that helps!

Comment: Try using [this script](https://pastebin.com/0iwCPUgd). (Taken from [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/joystick.html) )Just run that and see if it can detect anything. If it is not able to, then the problem is either with the hardware of the controller or the configuration settings on the computer.

Comment: yeah, that code didn't work either.  I'm thinking its a configuration issue with my computer.

Comment: How are you connecting to the computer? Have you in any way verified that it is truly connected? If you are on windows, go to the start menu and search "game controllers". Click on "Set up USB game controllers" . Turn on your controller and see if it shows up in the list. If it does not, your computer is not recognizing the controller.

Comment: I tried this it seems the controller wasn't connecting. I found a tutorial online turns out I didn't have all the drivers installed for windows to read PS3 controller. I didn't think that I needed specific drivers for PS3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine. Apparently, I had to download a specific set of drivers to make the PS3 controller compatible with windows so it could be read as an XBOX 360 controller.

There were some tutorials online that used SCP ToolKit driver installer to make the controller compatible, however, it did make it so I couldn't use my Bluetooth mouse for some reason.

Comment: I think some more information would be helpful. Maybe describe step by step what you did and post links to the tutorials (link only answers are not allowed, so you should also summarize the information that the tuts provide).